# is it possible to get parameters by function name in javascript

Tags: javascript, arguments

For example, I have a function defined as below:

```
var fn1 = function(obj, p1, p2) {}
```

Is it possible to get this function's parameters by the function name `fn1` outside fn1?
I want to make a new `fn2(p1, p2)` dynamically and in this function passing the obj to call `fn1`?
Anyone help on this? Many thanks.

Comment: Scope is dangerous territory in Javascript. What are you trying to do? A more concrete example would help.

Comment: very broad be more specific

Comment: I change the scope to obj, it is just a object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass the scope to the `function` like this:

```
var fn1 = function(scope, p1, p2) {}
```

I belive what you want is something like the `call` method. The `call` method is used to call a method on behalf of another object. It allows you to change the **this** object of a function from the original **context** to the new object specified by first arg. [`call` Method Ref. - JS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2ak8h2y(v=vs.94).aspx)

Here some example:

```
var fn1 = function(p1,p2){};

var fnThatCall = function(p1,p2){
   var scpe = this;
   fn1.call(scope,p1,p2);
};
```

Comment: yes, you are right, that is my meaning, but I want to define 'fnThatCall' dynamically based on the 'fn1' parameters, not hard coded. possible?

Comment: Sure, exists some approaches to do that, so one of them is this:  you can use the `arguments` objects that is a local variable  present in all `function` objects, it is an array with all arguments, so you need to abstract the name of the parameter and use this array. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87dw3w1k(v=vs.94).aspx